# How to clone each div individually respective of the parent

Tags: jquery

The target is to clone the a tag to my snippet. The problem is that, all the cloned elements are sitting in the same div, instead of their respective divs.

I have tried to loop them but every cloned is sitting on the same div.

```
<div class="product_image_wrapper">
    <a href="socks.html">
    <img src="socks.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="mysnippet"> // The objective here is that while we hover image above, then 'view product' will be shown. If user click, it will redirect to that a link. 
        <div class="myview">
            <a href="#">View product</a> // The a tag with socks.html should be cloned here
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product_image_wrapper">
    <a href="jean.html">
    <img src="jean.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="mysnippet"> // Likewise this mysnippet should clone only the a tag that's it's under. 
        <div class="myview">
            <a href="#">View product</a> // The a tag with jean.html should be cloned here
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product_image_wrapper">
    <a href="socks.html">
    <img src="socks.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="mysnippet"> 
        <div class="myview">
            <a href="#">View product</a>
            <a href="socks.html"><img src="socks.jpg"></a>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product_image_wrapper">
    <a href="jean.html">
    <img src="jean.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="mysnippet"> 
        <div class="myview">
            <a href="#">View product</a>
            <a href="jean.html"><img src="jean.jpg"></a>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your jquery code also so that we can see how you are cloning and we can help you.

Comment: $('.product_image_wrapper a').each(function (e) {
    var clone = $(this).clone();
    $('.myview').prepend(clone);
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Scope is wrong. You create a clone of all **.product_image_wrapper a** and put it into the first **.myview**. But i think you want to put it into the **.myview** next to the **a** you cloned, right?

Try this:

```
$('.product_image_wrapper a').each(function (e) { 
  // clone the element
  var clone = $(this).clone(); 
  // get the parent wrapper
  var wrapper = $(e).closest('.product_image_wrapper');
  // get myview
  var myview = wrapper.find('.myview');
  // prepend the clone
  myview.prepend(clone); 
});
```

My favorite is to operate direct on the parent. So you don't have to search it later:

```
// don't pick the "a" but the parent "product_image_wrapper"
$('.product_image_wrapper').each(function (e) { 
  // clone the element
  var clone = $(this).find('a').clone(); 
  // get myview
  var myview = $(e).find('.myview');
  // prepend the clone
  myview.prepend(clone); 
});
```

It's up to you which one would you like.